# Jquery datePicker Removed selected date class

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to remove class for selected date when form submit button is clicked because when a date have selected I need to reset datePicker without any selected date.

I tried

```
$('.weekday').removeClass('selected');
```

But it's not working.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set the datepicker value empty then

```
$('.weekday').val("");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about you want,but I think you can run this

```
$('.weekday').val('');
```

it will remove selected style from your date picker

Comment: I don't kown about your element that specified the css class ".weekday"

Comment: I don't kown about your element that specified the css class ".weekday"  ,But I assume you have code look like this <input type='text' class='weekday' name='date'>, if your selector class "weekday" not is the input element, You have to empty value of element that sync with jquery date picker for remove selected style. Sorry my english is not well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$('.ui-state-default').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
```